# Extracting value using Window and Partition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe in pyspark

```
id | value

1     0
1     1
1     0
2     1
2     0
3     0
3     0
3     1
```

I want to extract all the rows after the first occurrence of 1 in value column in the same id group. I have created Window with partition of Id but do not know how to get rows which are present after value 1.

Im expecting result to be

```
 id | value

    1     1
    1     0
    2     1
    2     0
    3     1
```

Comment: Do you have something that defines ordering within the window? Otherwise the results will be nondeterministic I think

Comment: I could order by only id column.

Comment: The underlying data model is a set, not a list, so e.g. for `id=1` the values 0, 1 and 0 can be processed in any order. If there is no shuffle, the order remains the same but would not build anything based on that assumption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below solutions may be relevant for this (It is working perfectly for small data but may cause the problem in big data if `id` are on multiple partitions)

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
         [1, 0],
         [1, 1],
         [1, 0],
         [2, 1],
         [2, 0],
         [3, 0],
         [3, 0],
         [3, 1]
    ],
    ['id', 'Value']
)
df.show()
+---+-----+
| id|Value|
+---+-----+
|  1|    0|
|  1|    1|
|  1|    0|
|  2|    1|
|  2|    0|
|  3|    0|
|  3|    0|
|  3|    1|
+---+-----+

#importing Libraries
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as W
import sys

#This way we can generate a cumulative sum for values 
df.withColumn(
    "sum",
    F.sum(
        "value"
    ).over(W.partitionBy(["id"]).rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0))
).show()
+---+-----+-----+
| id|Value|sum  |
+---+-----+-----+
|  1|    0|    0|
|  1|    1|    1|
|  1|    0|    1|
|  3|    0|    0|
|  3|    0|    0|
|  3|    1|    1|
|  2|    1|    1|
|  2|    0|    1|
+---+-----+-----+

#Filter all those which are having sum > 0
df.withColumn(
    "sum",
    F.sum(
        "value"
    ).over(W.partitionBy(["id"]).rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0))
).where("sum > 0").show()

+---+-----+-----+
| id|Value|sum  |
+---+-----+-----+
|  1|    1|    1|
|  1|    0|    1|
|  3|    1|    1|
|  2|    1|    1|
|  2|    0|    1|
+---+-----+-----+
```

> Before running this you must be sure that data related to ID should be partitioned and no id can be on 2 partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would need to:

1. Create a window partitioned by `id` and ordered the same way the dataframe already is
2. Keep only the rows for which there is a "one" before them in the window

AFAIK, there is no look up function within windows in Spark. Yet, you could follow this idea and work something out. Let's first create the data and import functions and windows.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

l = [(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0), (2, 1), (2, 0), (3, 0), (3, 0), (3, 1)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(l, ['id', 'value'])
```

Then, let's add an index on the dataframe (it's free) to be able to order the windows.

```py
indexedDf = df.withColumn("index", F.monotonically_increasing_id())
```

Then we create a window that only looks at the values before the current row, ordered by that index and partitioned by id.

```py
w = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("index").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)
```

Finally, we use that window to collect the set of preceding values of each row, and filter out the ones that do not contain `1`. Optionally, we order back by `index` because the windowing does not preserve the order by `id` column.

```py
indexedDf\
    .withColumn('set', F.collect_set(F.col('value')).over(w))\
    .where(F.array_contains(F.col('set'), 1))\
    .orderBy("index")\
    .select("id", "value").show()

+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|    1|
|  1|    0|
|  2|    1|
|  2|    0|
|  3|    1|
+---+-----+
```